# Loading entity 2 times in a single request, seems to be cached on second attempt

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In the same request, I am loading an entity 2 times:

```
IProduct product = ....

// some logic

IProduct product2 = ...
```

Both times, the exact same fetch method is used so the parameters are the same, by default does EF cache the data and not make another database call?

How can I force EF to fetch the data again and bypass any caching it might have?

Comment: This is going to depend very much on the details of how your project is configured, and the other code you've written.

Comment: Why are you expecting the same record to be different? The request should be short-lived enough that this isn't an expectation, more of an exception. Are you reading it, changing it, then trying to read it again in the same request? Sounds like a possible logic flaw in your code regardless of the issue you mention.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

```
IProduct product = db.Find(key);
IProduct product2 = db.Find(key); // this will get a cached value only if db is the same instance
```

... and by default, that is the only time it will retrieve a cached version, when you use `.Find` on one instance of a `DbContext`. `.Where` calls will not be cached, each will generate a new SQL query. So if you want to prevent it from caching, use `.Where(x => x.Id == key)` instead of `.Find(key)`.

Comment: I'm using this method ` DataContext.Set<E>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);`

Comment: Like I said, the only method that caches is .Find. FirstOrDefault will hit the database each time you invoke it by default.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the same `context` instance the `AsNoTracking()` method could be what you're looking for ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbquery.asnotracking%28v=vs.113%29.aspx))

```
Context.Set<Product>().AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.whatever).ToList();
```